# java.lang.IllegalStateException when updating JComboBox with setModel()?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, illegalstateexception

I was trying to updating JComboBox with setModel(). However, it throws a java.lang.IllegalStateException.
Specifically, I used a JTextField to point to the Editable component of the JComboBox, and Update the JComboBox every time the JTextField recieves a new input.

Can anyone tell me the reason?

```
package ui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame implements DocumentListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // tool bar
    private JToolBar topToolBar;
    private JTextField wordSearchField;
    private JComboBox<String> wordSearchTips;

    // window size
    private static final int width = 700;
    private static final int height = 500;

    public TestFrame() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        new TestFrame().CreateUI();
    }

    public void CreateUI() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        setResizable(false);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // bottom
        JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
        bottom.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, 480));
        bottom.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // top
        topToolBar = new JToolBar();
        topToolBar.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        topToolBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, 30));

        wordSearchTips = new JComboBox<String>();
        wordSearchTips.setEditable(true);
        wordSearchTips.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        wordSearchField = (JTextField) wordSearchTips.getEditor()
                .getEditorComponent();
        wordSearchField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);

        topToolBar.add(wordSearchTips);

        add(topToolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

        String keyword = wordSearchField.getText().trim();
        DefaultComboBoxModel<String> m = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>();
        ;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            m.addElement(i + "");
        }
        wordSearchTips.setModel(m);
        wordSearchTips.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        ((JTextField) wordSearchTips.getEditor().getEditorComponent())
                .setText(keyword);
        wordSearchTips.showPopup();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Here is the exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to mutate in notification
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.writeLock(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setText(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxEditor$1.setText(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxEditor.setItem(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.configureEditor(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI$Handler.propertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI$PropertyChangeHandler.propertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxUI$MetalPropertyChangeListener.propertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComboBox.setModel(Unknown Source)
    at ui.TestFrame.insertUpdate(TestFrame.java:94)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireInsertUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.replaceSelection(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit$DefaultKeyTypedAction.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Don't try and modify a `JTextComponent` or `Document` from within a `DocumentListener`

Comment: `DocumentListener` is notified when the `Document` is been modified, an attempt to modify it again would result in another notification to the `DocumentListener`, which would eventually result in a `StackOverFlowException`

Comment: What I got is not a StackOverFlowException, and it seems that it failed the first time it got into the function.

Comment: That's because the system is designed to stop you from doing this, by locking the `Document` from been update while it's been update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your code from the `insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)` in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`

Comment: Would you mind telling me about the reason or giving me some link?

Comment: I did as what you said. It do work without exception. However, every time I type a character in the JCombobox, the program seems to enter an infinite loop...

Comment: @flexwang Think for a second.  When the text field is modified, it calls your `DocumentListener`, which you then modify the field within, which then calls your `DocumentListener` and hello, infinite loop...

Comment: @MadProgrammer oh I see. It seems that I'd better implement a KeyAdapter rather a DocumentListener to avoid such infinite loop.

Comment: @flexwang It's not a means by which I would be comfortable doing it, but it may be your only real solution given the problems with `DocumentListener`.  Consider taking a look at the `AutoCompleteDecorator` in SwingLabs, SwingX library which does a similar thing

Answer (score 2):

Doing this can produce some very weird results.  The API is designed to protect against threaded updates and potential modifications that might cause infinite loops

In this case, the text field is modified, the `Document` is updated, the `DocumentListener` is notified and you try to change the field again, which would start the cycle again, except the `Document` has a guard to prevent you from doing just this very thing, hence the `Exception`.

What you need to do is two things.

1. You need to update the text field AFTER the `DocumentListener` has been notified.  As has already been stated, this can be achieved by using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`
2. Provide some kind of flag so you don't try and modify your field on events cause by you modifying the field due to `DocumentListener` events...confused yet?

Basically, this example uses `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to update the field AFTER the `DocumentListener` has completed it's event notifications and a simple `boolean` flag to provide a means to "ignore" updates that we have triggered...

It's messy, but it will get the job done...mostly...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame implements DocumentListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // tool bar
    private JToolBar topToolBar;
    private JTextField wordSearchField;
    private JComboBox<String> wordSearchTips;

    // window size
    private static final int width = 700;
    private static final int height = 500;

    public TestFrame() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        new TestFrame().CreateUI();
    }

    public void CreateUI() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        setResizable(false);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // bottom
        JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
        bottom.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, 480));
        bottom.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // top
        topToolBar = new JToolBar();
        topToolBar.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        topToolBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, 30));

        wordSearchTips = new JComboBox<String>();
        wordSearchTips.setEditable(true);
        wordSearchTips.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        wordSearchField = (JTextField) wordSearchTips.getEditor()
                .getEditorComponent();
        wordSearchField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);

        topToolBar.add(wordSearchTips);

        add(topToolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    }

    boolean beenModified = false;

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

        if (!beenModified) {
            beenModified = true;

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    String keyword = wordSearchField.getText().trim();
                    DefaultComboBoxModel<String> m = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        m.addElement(i + "");
                    }
                    wordSearchTips.setModel(m);
                    wordSearchTips.setSelectedIndex(-1);
                    ((JTextField) wordSearchTips.getEditor().getEditorComponent())
                            .setText(keyword);
                    wordSearchTips.showPopup();

                    beenModified = false;
                }
            });

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: @StanislavL I hate autocomplete comboboxes, to many things can go wrong and so many state changes to take into consideration, to not mention `Object` to `String` converstions...:P

Comment: I do like them in my IDE:-)